# Regular expression capturing repeated groups

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Hi so I have been trying to figure out how to capture these groups properly and I can't: http://www.debuggex.com/r/xOmFR78EkK3mATN4/0

In the example I need to capture each individual part of the expression in `test1 == 0` `test2 == 1` and `test3 == 2` Right now I only match test1 and test3 I can't figure out how I can get all of the expressions matched properly.

I will be using C++ and boost regex, though that shouldn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your test2 isn't getting captured because it's being captured by group 7, but the contents of group 7 are getting overwritten when it matches test3.

For boost regex, look at the documentation for [`match_flag_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_flag_type.html), specifically `match_extra`.

Comment: Ah well crap I can't do that because of the way the library was built. It doesn't have match extra enabled

Comment: @legion Well, that's tough, but not impossible. You notice how that part of your regex is sort of a loop? It should be possible for you to implement the looping in your code, and perform a regex match or search multiple times, changing your starting position each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost.Xpressive](http://boost.org/libs/xpressive) for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

using namespace boost::xpressive;

int main()
{
    std::string str( "testrule: test1 == 0 && test2 == 1 && test3 == 2 ; test desc" );

    sregex_compiler comp;
    regex_constants::syntax_option_type x = regex_constants::ignore_white_space;
    comp.compile("(? $test = )(([\\w\\.]+)\\s+(==|!=|>|<)\\s+([\\w\\.]+))", x);
    sregex test = comp.compile("^(\\w+):\\s+(? $test )(\\s&&\\s(? $test ))*\\s*;\\s*(.*)$", x);

    smatch what;
    if(regex_match(str, what, test))
    {
        for(smatch const & nested : what.nested_results())
            std::cout << nested[0].str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This program prints the following:

```
test1 == 0
test2 == 1
test3 == 2
```

It makes strategic use of [nested dynamic regexes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.grammars_and_nested_matches.dynamic_regex_grammars), which I don't believe Boost.Regex supports. The good news is that if you have Boost, the above should Just Work. Xpressive is a header-only library; that is, it doesn't need to be built.

You can make this far more efficient using Xpressive's [semantic actions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.semantic_actions_and_user_defined_assertions). That's not harder, but does forgo much of the regex syntax you're clearly familiar with.

Another option would be to build a simple parser using [Boost.Spirit](http://boost.org/libs/spirit), which is also header only.

HTH!